# How do I rebind the <Enter> key on Eclim displays (:ProjectProblems, :JavaCorrect, etc.) to the 'o' key

Tags: java, vim, eclim

How do I rebind the  key on Eclim displays (:ProjectProblems, :JavaCorrect, etc.) to the 'o' key? Both NERDTree, and BufExplorer use the 'o' key when you want to select an element. I want to maintain this convention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to look into the sourcecode of eclim.
For :JavaCorrect the corresponding file is found at `$ECLIM_INSTALLDIR/eclim/autoload/eclim/java/correct.vim` (or `org.eclim.jdt/vim/eclim/autoload/eclim/java/correct.vim` if you are looking at the github source).
At line 98, the mapping of `<cr>` can be found.

I don't think there is any other feasable way of remapping this key. I have already tried writing an `autocmd` to match for the filename (eg: `au BufEnter *.java_correct map ...`), but this was not possible. The buffers filename is set after all the events have fired (at least I think it is so).